# Select2 not working with DHTMLX Scheduler

Tags: jquery-select2, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using a calendar platform called dhtmlx scheduler. Within the calendar, when you click on a time, a dialog will pop up and show options for filling in an event. On this dialog I am including a select2 ajax control.
Unfortunately, the drop down display doesn't show properly - it is being displayed underneath the dialog box.

Does anyone know of a way to make the drop down results appear in the foreground?

Comment: how did you get your select2 initialised?